# Primefaces ultima how to start with

Tags: maven, primefaces, jsf-2

I've just bought primefaces premium theme. I've proceed like the maven project delivred with but the page has not rendered primefaces theme. As you can see in images.

[image: notworking]

Comment: It is not working because you don't migrate GuestPreference bean from the Ultima package to your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starter, you can copy GuestPreference.java from Ultima package to your application. It is Annotation based so copy it to a package which annotation scan.

Comment: thanks i've done and it is working! thanks very much